# Can't get faketime to work with nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to set up faking server time using libfaketime running nginx+php on ubuntu but no luck.

Here is what I've done:

1) Installed faketime:

```
$ wget http://www.code-wizards.com/projects/libfaketime/libfaketime-0.9.6.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf libfaketime-0.9.6.tar.gz
$ cd libfaketime-0.9.6
$ make
$ sudo make install 
$ echo "@2012-12-21 12:12:12" > /etc/faketimerc
```

2) added the following to my nginx.conf:

```
env LD_PRELOAD="/usr/local/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1";
```

3) Restarted nginx and php.

When I export LD_PRELOAD manually and then try date, it works, but when I do **`curl localhost`** or go to the website it gets the actual server date not the one from /etc/faketimerc

I've also tried setting LD_PRELOAD in :

- /etc/environment
- /etc/profile
- /etc/profile.d/LD_PRELOAD.sh
- /etc/default/nginx

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try set LD_PRELOAD for nginx (by root), not for user's shell:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1 /path/to/nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a txt file (eg: faketime.txt) and in it give the time you want
Eg:  `2015-06-27 18:30:00`

Then put the the following commands in the .config file

```
set.default.LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1
set.default.FAKETIME_TIMESTAMP_FILE=/home/Documents/faketime.txt
```